# Beautiful Mathematical Images

Tags: soft-question, big-list

My Maths department is re-branding itself, and we've been asked to find suitable images for the departmental sign. Do you have a favourite mathematical image that could be used for the background of an A1-sized sign?

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=math&tbs=imgo:1 gives an endless stream of clipart-type images.

Comment: My favorite image is the one created by Sam Derbyshire linked on [this page](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/).

Comment: @vadim123 ...and none of the 1000 or so that I looked at were suitable. Hence the question.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: That is gorgeous! Amazing that roots lead to such amazing pictures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I produced the following images, which I personally like ;-)

#### A part of the Mandelbrot set:

[image: A part of the Mandelbrot set]

---

#### A projective curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$:

[image: A projective curve in <span class=]$\mathbb{P}^2$" />

Comment: If you like one of these I can send you a HD version of it, which should be ok to be printed on a A1

Answer (score 6):

Penrose tiling, an example:

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling

Or any basic first year theorems (or more advanced) theorems like MVT, Taylor, BW, cardinalities, ordinals etc, in nice fonts or even as sculpture.

Complex but symmetric 3D objects like the Wolframram Alpha star for example, see also George Hart.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [Buddhabrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhabrot)?

[image: An example of the Buddhabrot]

You can say something to the effect of "Find your path through Mathematics." `:)`

Answer (score 4):

I find these look very nice, however I am not certain how the process that generates the vectors works (perlin noise).

Perlin lines:
[image: generated through perlin noise]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**[The first six books of the elements of Euclid, in which coloured diagrams and symbols
are used instead of letters for the greater ease of learners](https://archive.org/details/firstsixbooksofe00byrn)** (1847)
by *Oliver Bryne*

If you arent lazy, making a replica of any diagrams in this book will look great for your department.